# How does one prevent misdirection of file URLs when using .htaccess/

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess

Currently, I have a simple PHP website that has a list of animals. When a user selects an animal from the list, an AJAX function is called in an external JavaScript file. The AJAX function retrieves the animal's information from a database in the form of a JSON representation of the animal which appears in a div tag on index.php.

To test it, I have a function called within index.php with a hardcoded number. This function accurately returns the JSON representation when the website loads immediately.

As of right now, I'm trying to make it so if I go to localhost/1/ I get the JSON version of the first animal, and so forth. To do this, I am using an .htaccess document in an attempt to make $_GET['animalID'] equal the value typed next to localhost so it would work as if I chose the first item under dropdown menu.

I have written the following .htaccess document.

```
#Turning rewrite engine on

RewriteEngine on

#Rewrite to clean URL to hide php query

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !(?:css|js)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+) index.php?animalID=$1 [QSA,L]
```

As of right now, using just localhost by itself yields the expected response. However, when using localhost/1/ the entire javascript file breaks.

I get this error: `Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost/1/Assets/AnimalLoader.js”.`

Now, if it's trying to find AnimalLoader.js under localhost/1/Assets/AnimalLoader.js, I know it won't find it because Animal loader is under localhost/Assets/AnimalLoader.js. In spite of this, `$_GET['animalID']` is clearly showing the proper intended values when echoed onto the main page.  However, I don't understand why it's searching under the directory /1/, nor do I know how to prevent from this happening. I can't tell if this will happen with other files either.

Can anyone explain how to prevent this? Thanks in advance.

For reference, here is how I link my scripts.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="Assets/AnimalLoader.js" ></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `AnimalLoader.js` is off of the root of your site change the `src` to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Assets/AnimalLoader.js" ></script>
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that made a difference. That's interesting. Good to know. It seemed to fix the immediate issue.

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. This informs the community, a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you.

Comment: Yes, I was waiting for the timer. Apologies.